# ERROR: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, rest

**I have read many similar problems, but no solution worked for me.**

I am writing RESTful API using jersey for CRUD, thus I need to implement SQL sentence to perform the transactions. But for every transaction, the same error occurred that the program says my SQL syntax is wrong.

I have searched for many solutions but no one works for me, and I didn't found anything wrong in my SQL code

(Other 3 operations including create, delete and update shows familiar error)

Following is my Java code for reading:

```
  public HotelBean read(int hotelId, int roomId) {
    List<RoomBean> lBean = new ArrayList<RoomBean>();
    try {
      Connection conn = DBFactory.connectDB().getConn();
      Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT T1.HOTEL_ID, HOTEL_NAME, ROOM_ID, ROOM_NAME, OCCUPANCY, VACANCY, TOTAL_ROOM FROM HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO T1 INNER JOIN HPMSDB.HOTEL_INFO T2 ON T1.HOTEL_ID=T2.HOTEL_ID" + " WHERE T2.HOTEL_ID =" + hotelId + "AND T2.ROOM_ID="+ roomId);
      while (rs.next()) {
        RoomBean roomBean = new RoomBean();
        roomBean.setHotelId(rs.getInt(1));
        roomBean.setHotelName(rs.getString(2));
        roomBean.setRoomId(rs.getInt(3));
        roomBean.setRoomName(rs.getString(4));
        roomBean.setOccupancy(rs.getInt(5));
        roomBean.setVancancy(rs.getInt(6));
        roomBean.setTotalRoom(rs.getInt(7));
        lBean.add(roomBean);
      }
      conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    HotelBean hotelBean = new HotelBean();
    hotelBean.setRoomBean(lBean);
    return hotelBean;
  }
```

And the following is my database:

```
CREATE DATABASE HPMSDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8
DEFAULT COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HPMSDB.HOTEL_INFO;
CREATE TABLE HPMSDB.HOTEL_INFO (
HOTEL_ID INT NOT NULL,
HOTEL_NAME VARCHAR(64),
RESORT_MANAGE VARCHAR(64),
PRIMARY KEY(HOTEL_ID)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO;
CREATE TABLE HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO (
HOTEL_ID INT NOT NULL,
ROOM_ID INT NOT NULL,
ROOM_NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
OCCUPANCY INT,
VACANCY INT,
TOTAL_ROOM INT,
PRIMARY KEY(HOTEL_ID, ROOM_ID)
);
```

Following is the error message for reading:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T2.ROOM_ID=2' at line 1
```

Following is the error message for creating:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE HOTEL_ID =2 AND ROOM_ID=1' at line 1
```

I was really confused about where it is wrong that all create, update, read and delete shows the same error.

Thank you for your time and have a good day!

Comment: Can you change

    =" + hotelId + "AND

To

    =" + hotelId + " AND

You need a spacing between the id and "AND"

Comment: For starters mysql <> sql server. They are completely different DBMS. But regardless of which DBMS you are using your query is tragically flawed. You are building up a string and executing it. This is how sql injection happens and your company appears on the nightly news as the latest data breach victim. You need to use parameterized queries.

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee Thank you for your reply. But I have tried many spacing formats, they all won't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Well the problem is twofold..

One is that there is no space before the AND keyword in your string concatenate:

```
SELECT T1.HOTEL_ID, HOTEL_NAME, ROOM_ID, ROOM_NAME, OCCUPANCY, VACANCY, TOTAL_ROOM 
FROM HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO T1 INNER JOIN HPMSDB.HOTEL_INFO T2 
ON T1.HOTEL_ID=T2.HOTEL_ID" + " WHERE T2.HOTEL_ID =" + hotelId + "AND T2.ROOM_ID="+ roomId
```

Will become like:

```
SELECT T1.HOTEL_ID, HOTEL_NAME, ROOM_ID, ROOM_NAME, OCCUPANCY, VACANCY, TOTAL_ROOM 
FROM HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO T1 INNER JOIN HPMSDB.HOTEL_INFO T2 
ON T1.HOTEL_ID=T2.HOTEL_ID WHERE T2.HOTEL_ID =1234AND T2.ROOM_ID=9999
                                              ^^^^^^^
                                              LOOK!
```

**But the bigger problem is that youre using string concat to put values into an SQL.** This is a superb way to get hacked when you go live

Please use [parameterized queries](http://bobby-tables.com)

The site linked above has advice on using PreparedStatement. Remember that if you ever get into a situation where you think "i want to use parameters, but I just HAVE to build this SQL by string concat; there is no other way" - remember *there is nothing stopping you from concatenating a parameter* and then filling the parameter with a value; always always avoid concatenating **values** into your SQLs

Imagine you have two arrays:

```
columns[0] = "hotelid";
values[0] = "RoyalPalace";
columns[1] = "roomnum";
values[1] = "99";
```

You might think you have to make your sql like:

```
string sql = "select * from hotels where 1=1 ";
for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
  sql = sql + " AND " + columns[i] + " = " + values[i]; // no no; do not concat values in!
}
```

Concat parameters in, and set them (Hibernate syntax):

```
string sql = "select * from hotels where 1=1 ";
for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
  sql = sql + " AND " + columns[i] + " = :p" + i; // yes, concat a parameter named pX in!
}
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);

for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
  query.setString(":p"+i, values[i]); // give the parameters a value
}
```

This is a lame example I know.. But just in case you ever find yourself in a scenario where you think you need to concat values in - you never do

Comment: Thank you for answering! But one problem is my other code also shows the same error, like this:`String sql = "UPDATE HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO SET OCCUPANCY = OCCUPANCY + " + roomBean.getOccupancy() + ", VACANCY = VACANCY - " + roomBean.getOccupancy() + " WHERE HOTEL_ID =" + roomBean.getHotelId() + " AND ROOM_ID=" + roomBean.getRoomId();`

Comment: You'll need to dump the SQL you generated into a log and then paste it into something that can run it against the db. It will be failing for some similar reason, like one of those getXXX() is returning "" nor null etc meaning your SQL has a syntax error. PLEASE use parameters. It's also really easy to see where you went wrong when you use parameters , because your SQL is like `UPDATE HPMSDB.ROOM_INFO SET OCCUPANCY = OCCUPANCY + :occu, VACANCY = VACANCY - :occu WHERE HOTEL_ID = :hotelid AND ROOM_ID= :roomid` i.e. the syntax is correct right now, no matter what values are in the parameters.

Comment: And also your SQL doesn't explode as soon as you try to check in a person named `Patrick O'Leary`